# Dynamic menu or list in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, togglebutton

Been trying to figure out how to do the dynamic list or menu with the JSON data format below:

```
        modules: [
            {
                module_id: 1,
                module_parent_id: 0,
                module_name: "Module 1",
                status: true,
                child: 
                    [
                        {
                        module_id: 2,
                        module_parent_id: 1,
                        module_name: "Module 2",
                        status: true,
                        child: 
                            [
                                {
                                module_id: 3,
                                module_parent_id: 1,
                                module_name: "Module 3",
                                status: true,
                                },
                                {
                                    module_id: 4,
                                    module_parent_id: 1,
                                    module_name: "Module 4",
                                    status: true,
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            module_id: 5,
                            module_parent_id: 1,
                            module_name: "Module 5",
                            status: true,
                        },
                    ]
            },
            {
                module_id: 6,
                module_parent_id: 0,
                module_name: "Module 6",
                status: false
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Already tried using v-for but it's not dynamic:

```
<ul v-for="module in modules">
    <li>
        {{module.module_name}}
    </li>
    <ul v-for="module_child in module.child" v-if="module.child">
        <li>
            {{module_child.module_name}}
        </li>
        <ul v-for="module_sub_child in module_child.child" v-if="module_child.child">
            <li>
                {{module_sub_child.module_name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**NOTE: I need to use v-for instead of creating a method since I am using Vue-JS toggle button plugin: https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-toggle-button. It doesn't render the plugin when I tried to do the method. (If there's no other way in doing this, maybe I'll do my own custom toggle-button..)

Here is the [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGhzK.png) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If plugin is not working, its either you forgot to add `Vue.use(ToggleButton))` before using it or you are trying to place it inside your template directly.

For other components to work inside your own you must initialize 
it like this

```
import ToggleButton from 'vue-js-toggle-button'
export default {
  data: function () { . . . },
  components: {
    'toggle-button':  ToggleButton,
  },
  template: `
   <ul v-for="module in modules">
     <li>
       <toggle-button @change="onChangeEventHandler"/>
     </li>
   </ul>`
}
```

Comment: Hi @ken, I think Vue doesn't render or use the plugin if I use v-html. Because I have a function that computes and construct the html elements. Something like this:
`<div v-html="menuBuilder(modules)"></div> 

*script*
methods: { 
     menuBuilder: function(data) { 
          create or construct the menu... 
     }
}`